# find all duplicates in an array in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to find all the duplicates in the `attachmentForms` list in Angualar 8. I searched through a few posts and below is the code that I could come up with but I am still unable to set `isDuplicate` as `true` for name: `Document1`. I appreciate any help on this.

```
export interface AttachmentForm {
  name: string;
  isDuplicate: boolean;
}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.attachmentForms = [
      {name: 'Document1', isDuplicate: false},
      {name: 'Document2', isDuplicate: false},
      {name: 'Document1', isDuplicate: false},
      {name: 'Document3', isDuplicate: false},
    ];
   this.findDuplicates() ;
  }
 findDuplicates() {
    const newArr: AttachmentForm[] = [];
    this.attachmentForms.forEach((item, index) => {
      if (newArr.findIndex(i => i.name === item.name) === -1) {
        item.isDuplicate = false;
      } else {
        item.isDuplicate = true;
      }
      newArr.push(item);
    });
    this.attachmentForms = newArr;
  }
```

Comment: Is `findDuplicates` getting called? Also you don't need to do `newArr.push(item);` in both the `if` and `else` statement you can just do it after both statements since a conditional statement is synchronous. Much like whatever comes after a `for` loop.

Comment: @MattCroak I have updated the question according addressing your comments, thank you for letting me about the changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `findDuplicates()` to `this.findDuplicates()`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.attachmentForms = [
        { name: 'Document1', isDuplicate: false },
        { name: 'Document2', isDuplicate: false },
        { name: 'Document1', isDuplicate: false },
        { name: 'Document3', isDuplicate: false },
    ];
    this.findDuplicates();
}

findDuplicates() {
    const newArr: AttachmentForm[] = [];
    this.attachmentForms.forEach((item) => {
        if (this.attachmentForms.filter(i => i.name === item.name).length > 1) {
            item.isDuplicate = true;
        } else {
            item.isDuplicate = false;
        }
        newArr.push(item);
    });
    this.attachmentForms = newArr;
}
```

Here is a Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nl8zxc

Comment: Not adding this while calling `findDuplicates` was a editing mistake from my side while posting this question. Thank you for letting me know.t I am still unable to set `isDuplicate` as true for name: `Document1`. Can you please help

Comment: Only one `Document1` row has `isDuplicate = true`, other `Document1` row has `isDuplicate =false` with the current code. @3limin4t0r and @shareedit gave a better solution where both  `Document1` row has `isDuplicate = true`, unfortunately they deleted the answer: Below is the code: `const counter = new Map();
this.attachmentForms
    .forEach(({name}) => counter.set(name, (counter.get(name) || 0) + 1));
this.attachmentForms
    .forEach(item => (item.isDuplicate = counter.get(item.name) !== 1));`

Comment: I've update the stackblitz and example code to produce the results you were looking for. I tried the code you posted, but it did not yield the results you wanted in my stack blitz. It's possible I missed a line